# How to correctly use IF AND in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Here is an example of the workbook I have:

Single cell (G2): "Aug Wk2"

And here is the table I am working with called "Table1"

| Project Name | Actual Compl Date | Week of Month | Active/Planned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FirstProj | Sept 5 | Sept Wk1 | Planned |
| SecondProj | Aug 5 | Aug Wk1 | Planned |
| ThirdProj |  | Aug Wk2 | Active |
| SecondProj | Aug 5 | Aug Wk1 | Planned |

So, what I would like to do here, is have the Table1[Active/Planned] column dynamically update between "Active" or "Planned". Here are my conditions:

IF Table1[Week Of Month] = G2 **AND** Table1[Actual Completion Date] IS BLANK **then** set cell to "Active" **ELSE** set cells to "Planned".

I've tried using a function like this:

```
=IF(AND(Table1[Week of Month] = G2,ISBLANK(Table1[Actual Completion Date])), "Active", "Planned")
```

but it only seems to fill one cell rather than going through the whole column. I'd appreciate any guidance, thank you!

Comment: you need to use the `@` to reference the cell properly on the line:  `=IF(AND(Table1[@Week of Month] = G2,ISBLANK(Table1[@Actual Completion Date])), "Active", "Planned")`

Comment: Also realize that if the value in `Actual Compl Date` is put there by a formula, then ISBLANK will return FALSE even if the formula returns an empty string `""`.  ISBLANK only returns TRUE if the cell is truly empty, no value and no formula.

Comment: I tried using the @ to reference the cell but I am still running into the same issue. Also, Actual Compl Date is entered manually so thankfully I wont have to worry about non empty strings

Comment: With the `@` it works for me.

Comment: Make sure there are not spaces that are in Week of Month that are not in the value in G4.  And that the Empty cell is truly empty without a space or other non printable character.

Comment: I wouldn't trust your cell reference w/o absolute referencing.   $G$2  

Also, Sometimes it's a good idea to separate the two parts of your 'AND' and put them  in their own columns and just read down the table to be sure everything's evaluating as you expect.  Might help diagnose the issue

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner for the help, it seems to be working now. If I did want to use a better formula or method for evaluating if cells are empty, what would be a better way other than ISBLANK?

Comment: @RyanB. Thanks for the suggestion! I've put in absolute referencing and I will try your suggestion with two columns for the 'AND'

Comment: I always use: `Table1[Actual Completion Date]=""` instead.  Then it does not matter if the cell is blank or if an empty string is returned.  and it is less typing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Scott Craner and @Ryan B. for the suggestions I have been using this formula to get everything running:

```
=IF(AND(Table1[@[Week of Month]]= $G$2,Table1[@[Actual Completion Date]] = ""), "Active", "Planned")
```

If there are any better solutions, I'd love to hear them.